# variable en un nuevo doc de php me da error

Tags: php

necesito guardar una nueva variable en un documento que estoy generando en php pero me tira error ( lo que estoy haciendo es en una variable de php guardo un documento html y dentro de este mismo inserto unas lineas php pero al querer insertar cierta parte me da este error).

** syntax error unexpected eof expecting t_string or t_variable or t_num_string

esta es la parte del error

//aqui arriba hay mas codigo que no me tira ningun error

```
?php while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()):


     //aqui me marca el error      $r=$fila['res'];



                ?>
```

// debajo también tengo insertado mas código sin problema

se tal vez porque me puede estar generando error ya que no esta definida aun pero hay alguna manera de que no me genere error o ignorarlo?

Comment: No veo que estes cerrando el while.

Comment: lo has copiado y pegado? no sera result en vez de resul?? ese error me da la espina que puede ser por eso

Comment: Trata de poner `var_dump($fila);` para que te muestre lo que esta llegando igual te da alguna pista de lo que sucede.

Answer (score -2):

mira de poner el while a si:

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resul)):
```

para cuando carge el valor de `$fila['res']` sea un string.

Comment: fetch_assoc no existe, el lo esta usando correctamente.

Comment: me falto poner mysqli_ , ya lo he rectificado.

Comment: Pero eso es por procedimientos, el usuario parece que lo esta haciendo por objetos.